# Android KSOAP2 Error

Tags: android

I am using the jar(ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies) and have a web -

`services.url = http://62.244.199.18:8888/ergo-ergoService-context-root/ergoSoapHttpPort?WSDL`

and my code is below

```
private static final String METHOD_NAME = "checkloginnew";
private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ergoconn/Ergo.wsdl/checkloginnew";
private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://ergoconn/Ergo.wsdl";
private static final String URL = "http://62.244.199.18:8888/ergo-ergoService-context-root/ergoSoapHttpPort?WSDL";

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
pi.setName("pPid");
pi.setValue(1149688);
pi.setType(BigDecimal.class);
request.addProperty(pi);

PropertyInfo pi2 = new PropertyInfo();
pi2.setName("pPass");
pi2.setValue("074920");
pi2.setType(String.class);
request.addProperty(pi2);

SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL); 
httpTransport.debug = true;
httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

But I get an error `"Caught exception while handling request: unrecognized operation: {http://ergoconn/Ergo.wsdl}checkloginnew"`

```
In my httpTransport.responseDump:
<faultcode>env:Client</faultcode><faultstring>Caught exception while handling request: unrecognized operation: {http://ergoconn/Ergo.wsdl}checkloginnew</faultstring></env:Fault>
```

Thanks very much

Comment: Are you sure that the namespace of the service is`"http://ergoconn/Ergo.wsdl"`?

Comment: Please put your Parsing Code into Try-Catch Block, And Handle Exception In Catch block

Comment: have you add that Kasoap file into your BuildPath ..??

Comment: so had anybody fixed this issue? I've tried various answers on web post, cross checked and tried many things like namespace url, operation name, method name, removing adding lib etc. When I try the webservice on a browser it works but not inside android app using lib ksoap2.